# DataGrid decimal format converter

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have never used the wpf datagrid before and am trying to format some decimal columns to use a specific value for the format that is based on other columns values of the row.

Using Infragistics XamDataGrid in the past, I was able to just set styles for the XamCurrencyEditor, setting values for "Format" and "Mask" and use the multi value converter I wrote, passing along the DataItem.

The grid columns are created programatically.  So, I create a field like so:

```
var field = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = item.Name, Binding = new Binding("[" + item.Name + "].Value") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay } };
```

This field will contain decimal values (even though the column is just a text column).

How can I add some formatting to this column that takes into account some other values in the data object?  I am not sure how to reference the actual bound data row itself to pass along that data along with the cells value to the converter.

Comment: Any specific reason for the downvote, so I can avoid it next time?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it will work if the decimal is really string but this is XAML syntax for a decimal property

Binding StringFormat=DecValue: {0:N2}}

Comment: Thanks Blam.  Do you know how it would work if I needed the format (number of decimals) to be calculated based on another column of the row?

Comment: You would need a multivalue converter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter.aspx

Comment: Hey Blam.  I understand multivalue converters.  The thing is I do not know what to actually bind to, ie. how to access the bound data row in the datagrid.

Comment: Why can't you just bind to the properties directly?

Comment: I can, but I need access to the object that is the current rows data context don't I?  That is what I don't know how to get to.  So if I defined a multivalue converter for the column and I want one of the parameters to be the data context of that row, how would I do that?

Comment: What is so hard here?  That row is that binding. You bind to the other properties just like you bound to this one.   Binding("[" + item.Name + "].Value")   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx